How to run .sh file in wsl2 from Idea in Windows
I can run .sh file in wsl2 from windows explorer via bat file
@echo off
wsl -e sh -c "\"$(wslpath '%1')\""
PAUSE

How to do the same from Idea IDE (in windows) for example by double clicking or other simple way.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

So.... You have IDEA inside WSL2 OR in Windows?

And since you mentioned IDEA, is it IntelliJ IDEA for Java? Which gives rise to 2 more questions. 1. Do you want to run from inside Java program OR just want to execute .sh purely from InteliJ IDEA IDE?

If you are trying to run shell script purely from IDEA, then refer this documentation.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shell-scripts.html
